# How to write quotes with your python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, quotes, double-quotes

I want to know how to write this `''` with script using `python`

Because I Don't Know How To Write this from script using python `''`

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from random import *
import pyautogui as pg


time.sleep(2)
for i in range(1,510):
    pg.typewrite('')
    # here i want to type quotes in typewrite
```

## here i want to type quotes in typewrite

i want to write quotes in notepad with my `script` but it's not `writing` quotes if some chracter in abc or 123 it writing

Thanks!

is there any special character like `\n` or what is?

Comment: I so wanted to answer `''''''''`. Alas, that's just the concatenation of 4 empty strings, not a triple-quoted string containing two single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use double quotes:

```
    pg.typewrite("''")
```

Comment: i get this error `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

Comment: @MaxiMouse I replied on my phone, that’s why.

Answer (score 2):

You should use escape character, which is `\` for most cases:

```py
pg.typewrite('\'\'')
```

Escape character (`\`) will treat `'` as literal character instead of a string identifier.

Comment: But `"''"` doesn't look so complicated.

Comment: Yes indeed, I just wanted to emphasize the thing *escape character* and what does it do. `"''"` would totally work too.